# How to stop submit event initiated by .trigger()?

Tags: jquery, forms, events

I'm capturing all the submit events using `document.captureEvents`. In one page `trigger()` is used to submit the form. I'm able to capture it, but I'm not able to stop the propagation. I tried `stopPropagation` as well as `return false`.

Is there any other way to stop this propagation?

I'm using Backbone as well as rivets. It's a bit complicated to describe the entire code. 
So in brief, I've a backbone view, where I'm triggering submit() with .trigger

In my index.html, some where before the view renders, I've document.captureEvents(Event.SUBMIT)

With that I'm able to capture my submit event from Backbone view. But I'm not able to stop its propagation. The following is my code to capture events.

```
document.captureEvents(Event.SUBMIT);
document.onsubmit=function(event)
{

event.stopPropagation();
console.log(event);
alert('submit cap eve');
};
```

Comment: Tried `event.preventDefault()`? Without seeing your code structure it is hard to know why you're having issues and offer a solution.

Comment: what happened when you tried `return false`?

Comment: You need to share more context to the problem... like who is triggering the event, where you are calling `return false` and how is the actual submission happening etc

Comment: Please provide code. It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve and where youre going wrong.

Comment: I tried preventDefault also..